# Groovy expando dynamic set name

Tags: dynamic, groovy, expando

Is it possibly to dynamically set the class of an expando??

Having set

```
jr = new Expando()
```

Is there a way to

```
def end = 'name'
```

so that

```
jr.end
```

will actually give me the value stored in

```
jr.name
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, maybe this will help

```
jr = new Expando()
jr.end = 'name'
jr.name = jr.end

assert jr.end == jr.name
assert jr.end == 'name'
```

Comment: Maybe I haven't asked it in a logical way

By changing the def end I want to be able to create lots of different classes

i.e
jr.name
jr.house
jr.field

so that I can assign value to each of these but only if they get created.

Answer (score 0):

fixed it, need to assign a value at the same time. Doh!

```
def value = 'some value'
jr."$end" = value
```